# javascript:Using the replace() to replace text in html

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to use the replace() function to adjust the above code to show the text: Is this all?! while keeping the text added in the innerHTML

```
 <p id="str">Click the button for a surprise.</p>
 <form action="#">
 <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Enter">
 </form>

 function myFunction(){
 document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = "Is this all there is?";
 str.replace(str, "Is this all?!")
 }
```

Comment: how is the behaviour now / what is not working?

Comment: Its only outputs Is this all there is? when the button is clicked I'm trying to add is this all?! to the end of that. But I need to use the Replace() method.

Comment: You want the result to be "Is this all there is? Is this all?!" or what you want the result to be?

Comment: str should replace something in the tet you have, it cannot replace anything if there is anything to replace, wht you are asking is to append the text to the current text.

Comment: function myFunction(){
            var str = document.getElementById('str').innerHTML="Is this all there is?";
            
            var replace = str.replace(str, "Is this all?!")
            document.getElementById('str').innerHTML= replace;
            
            }

Comment: dude, you are using replace() function wrong! you aren't replace anything since you are giving the same string in parameter. I made a reply explaining that. To change a value you don't need to use replace(), just set document.getElementById('str').innerHTML= "text". Easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<p id="str">Click the button for a surprise.</p>
<form action="#">
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Enter">
</form>


function myFunction(){
var str = document.getElementById('str');
str.innerHTML = "Is this all there is? <moretext>";
str.innerHTML.replace("<moretext>", "Is this all?!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know what `replace()` function is made for. This function replace some piece of string by another string, this is not used to replace the whole string value. **This is not made to replace HTML text!**

see an example of replace in javascript:

```
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace("Microsoft","W3Schools");
```

The result would be: "Visit **W3Schools**!" , okay?

learn more at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Now, see an example to replace HTML text:

```
 document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = "Is this all?!"
```

So, that's what your code is suposed to be:

```
function myFunction(){
     //Set value at innerHTML
     document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = "Is this all there is?";

     //now "Is this all there is?" is stored in str variable
     var str = document.getElementById('str').innerHTML;

     //set another text for innerHTML
     document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = "Is this all?!"


 }
```

also, you can't store a text in innerHTML without changing it for user. So now the text that you want to store is in `str` variable

basically you misunderstood `replace()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
  var currentText = document.getElementById('str').innerHTML;
  var resultText = currentText + " Is this all?!";
  document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = resultText;
}
```